# Calculate expected number of heads in 10+$\xi$ coin tosses (GRE problem)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, geometric-probability, gre-exam

This is a problem from a preparatory GRE [preparatory GRE test](https://math.uchicago.edu/%7Emin/GRE/files/week1.pdf) made by guys form University of Chicago.

**Problem:**
A man flips $10$ coins. With $H$ the number of heads, and $T$ the number of tails, the man then flips $\max \left\{2 H-T^2, 0\right\}$ coins. What is the expected number of heads of both groups?

---

**My solution (giving wrong answer):**
Let $X$ be the random variable corresponding to the number of heads in both groups. Note that $2H-T^2<0$ for $H<7$ and $2H-T^2>0$ for $H\geq 7.$
To my understanding, the answer must be $$\mathbb{E}(X)=\mathbb{E}(H | 2H-T^2\leq 0) \mathbb{P}(2H-T^2\leq 0) +\mathbb{E}(\xi_1+\xi_2+\xi_3+\xi_4)\mathbb{P}(2H-T^2 > 0),$$
where $\xi_1=7+\text{"number of heads in 5 additional tosses"},\\ \xi_2=8+\text{"number of heads in 12 additional tosses"},\\ \xi_3=9+\text{"number of heads in 17 additional tosses"},\\ \xi_4=10+\text{"number of heads in 100 additional tosses"}.$

Now let's try to carefully calculate that.

1. $\mathbb{E}(\xi_1+\xi_2+\xi_3+\xi_4)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^4\mathbb{E}(\xi_i)=(7+2.5)+(8+6)+(9+8.5)+(10+50)=101.$
2. $\mathbb{P}(2H-T^2\leq 0)=\mathbb{P}(H<7)=\frac{1}{2^{10}}+\frac{10}{2^{10}}+\frac{C_{10}^2}{2^{10}}+\frac{C_{10}^3}{2^{10}}+\frac{C_{10}^4}{2^{10}}+\frac{C_{10}^5}{2^{10}}+\frac{C_{10}^6}{2^{10}}=\frac{848}{2^{10}}.$
   Consequently, $\mathbb{P}(2H-T^2> 0)=1-\frac{848}{2^{10}}=\frac{176}{2^{10}}.$
3. Finally,
   \begin{align*} 
   &\mathbb{E}(H | 2H-T^2\leq 0)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^6 n \mathbb{P}(H=n | H<7)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^6 n \frac{\mathbb{P}(H=n \text{ and } H<7)}{\mathbb{P}(H<7)}=\\
   &=\frac{1}{\mathbb{P}(H<7)}\sum\limits_{n=0}^6 n \mathbb{P}(H=n)=\frac{2^{10}}{848} \sum\limits_{n=0}^6 n \frac{C_{10}^n}{2^{10}}=\frac{1}{848} \sum\limits_{n=0}^6 n C_{10}^n=\frac{3820}{848}.
   \end{align*}

So,
$$\mathbb{E}(X)=\frac{3820}{848} \frac{848}{2^{10}} +101 \frac{176}{2^{10}}=\frac{3828+101 \cdot 176}{2^{10}} > 21.$$

---

**My questions:**

1. Where did I make a mistake? According to the authors, correct answer lies between $0$ and $8$. I did the computations on a calculator, so there must be a conceptual error here.
2. Are there ways to simplify the solution? May be with some geometric interpretation or clever observations. In a real exam there are 2.5 minutes per problem, and I am not sure how one is supposed to finish this so quickly.

Thank you.

Comment: I'd just condition on the number of heads tossed initially.  Thus $E=5+\sum_{i=7}^{10}p_i\times (2i-(10-i)^2)\times \frac 12$, where $p_i=\binom {10}i\times \frac 1{2^{10}}$ is the probability of tossing exactly $i$ Heads.  Not sure I'd want to do it by hand rapidly...

Comment: How exact of an answer do you need? Is the authors' "between 0 and 8" good enough?

Comment: Not following what you wrote...the maximum possible number of heads is $30$, right?  Very low probability of that.  And a high probability of a much smaller number.  Even if you threw $10$ heads initially (low probability), you only expect to toss $20$ altogether.

Comment: @lulu: Seems max number of heads is $30$--from $10$ on the first $10$ tosses plus $20$ in the bonus throws. But as you say, very unlikely ($1$ in about a billion).

Comment: Specifically, why do you talk about $100$ additional tosses?  The most you could possibly toss is when if you get $10$ $H$ initially, and in that case you get $2\times 10-10^2=20$ additional tests.  I agree with your values $5, 12, 17$ for the other cases.

Comment: @paw88789  I wrote $30$.  Well, I had $20$ first in error, but I corrected it to $30$.

Comment: @paw88789 Yes, that would answer my second question completely, thanks

Comment: @lulu Damn, you are completely right, thanks. In my head I calculated $H^2$ instead of $2H$. So, the maximum number of additional tosses is indeed 20 and my calculations (after fixing this mistake) must give answer $\frac{3828+61 \cdot 176}{2^{10}} > 14$ which is still a bit too big, unfortunately

Comment: Just quickly...the expected number of additional heads assuming we have at least $7$ initially is $\{\frac 52, \frac {12}2, \frac {17}2, \frac {20}2\}$ and of course these must be weighed by the (low) probabilities of being in those cases.  You can pretty much ignore the last two for that reason.  You numbers are far too high.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point needing an adjustment is:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}[X]
&=\mathbb{E}[\ H\ |\  2H-T^2\ \leq 0]\cdot \mathbb{P}(H\le 6\ ,\ T\ge 4\ ,\ 2H-T^2\leq 0) 
\\
&\qquad\qquad+\mathbb{E}[\ \xi_1\ ]\cdot \mathbb{P}(H=7\ ,\ T= 3\ ,\ 2H-T^2 =5)\\
&\qquad\qquad+\mathbb{E}[\ \xi_2\ ]\cdot \mathbb{P}(H=8\ ,\ T= 2\ ,\ 2H-T^2 =12)\\
&\qquad\qquad+\mathbb{E}[\ \xi_3\ ]\cdot \mathbb{P}(H=9\ ,\ T= 1\ ,\ 2H-T^2 =17)\\
&\qquad\qquad+\mathbb{E}[\ \xi_4\ ]\cdot \mathbb{P}(H=10\ ,\ T= 0\ ,\ 2H-T^2 =20)\\
&=
\sum_{0\le n\le 6}n\cdot\frac 1{2^{10}}\binom {10}n
\\&\qquad\qquad
+\left(7+5\cdot \frac 12\right)\cdot\frac 1{2^{10}}\binom {10}7
\\&\qquad\qquad
+\left(8+12\cdot \frac 12\right)\cdot\frac 1{2^{10}}\binom {10}8
\\&\qquad\qquad
+\left(9+17\cdot \frac 12\right)\cdot\frac 1{2^{10}}\binom {10}9
\\&\qquad\qquad
+\left(10+20\cdot \frac 12\right)\cdot\frac 1{2^{10}}\binom {10}{10}\\
&=
10\cdot \frac 12
\color{gray}{-7\cdot\frac 1{2^{10}}\binom {10}7
-8\cdot\frac 1{2^{10}}\binom {10}8
-9\cdot\frac 1{2^{10}}\binom {10}9
-10\cdot\frac 1{2^{10}}\binom {10}{10}}
\\&\qquad\qquad
+\left(\color{gray}{7}+5\cdot \frac 12\right)\cdot\frac 1{2^{10}}\binom {10}7
\\&\qquad\qquad
+\left(\color{gray}{8}+12\cdot \frac 12\right)\cdot\frac 1{2^{10}}\binom {10}8
\\&\qquad\qquad
+\left(\color{gray}{9}+17\cdot \frac 12\right)\cdot\frac 1{2^{10}}\binom {10}9
\\&\qquad\qquad
+\left(\color{gray}{10}+20\cdot \frac 12\right)\cdot\frac 1{2^{10}}\binom {10}{10}
\\
&=\frac 12\left(
10
+5\cdot\frac{120}{1024}
+12\cdot\frac{45}{1024}
+17\cdot\frac{10}{1024}
+20\cdot\frac{1}{1024}
\right)
\\
&=5+\frac 1{2048}(600+540+170+20)
=5+\frac {1330}{2048}
=5+\frac {665}{1024}
\\
&=5.6494140625\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
Here, the mean of the number of heads in an $N$ times repeated Bernoulli experiment with probabilities $p$ for the positive result is $Np$.
The above should be doable as it is in five minutes, rough approximations lead also quickly to an upper bound.

---

Computer check:

```
sage: p = 1/2

sage: sum([n                         * binomial(10, n)*p^10 for n in [0.. 6]]) + \
....: sum([(n + (2*n -(10 - n)^2)*p) * binomial(10, n)*p^10 for n in [7..10]])
5785/1024

sage: _.n()
5.64941406250000
```

Comment: Perhaps, it is a dumb question, but how did you immediately know that $\mathbb{E}[\ H\ |\  2H-T^2\ \leq 0]\cdot \mathbb{P}(H\le 6\ ,\ T\ge 4\ ,\ 2H-T^2\leq 0)=\sum\limits_{0\le n\le 6}n\cdot\frac 1{2^{10}}\binom {10}n?$ I had to calculate both factors and multiply them together to get his formula.

Comment: We split the space into the events where $H=n$, for $n$ running between zero and six. So the expression to be computed is $$\sum_{0\le n\le 6} \Bbb E[H\cdot 1_{H=n}]=\sum_{0\le n\le 6} \Bbb E[n\cdot 1_{H=n}]=\sum_{0\le n\le 6} n\Bbb E[ 1_{H=n}]=\sum_{0\le n\le 6} n\Bbb P(H=n)\ .$$

Comment: Oh, I got it. Perhaps, I should have started with writing $\mathbb{E}(X)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{10}\mathbb{E}(X | H=n) \mathbb{P}(H=n)=\left(\sum\limits_{n=0}^6 n \mathbb{P}(H=n)\right)+ \left(\sum\limits_{n=7}^{10}\mathbb{E}(X | H=n) \mathbb{P}(H=n)\right)$ and then I would not have gotten confused in the first place. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you include $\mathbb E(\xi_1 + \xi_2 + \xi_3 + \xi_4)$ in your expression for the total expectation; you need to weigh the scenarios by probability. I'm also not sure where the $100$ in your definition of $\xi_4$ comes from. Assuming your other calculations are correct, I get an answer of $$\frac{5785}{1024} \approx 5.65.$$

As for how you can approximate this quickly: you can quickly estimate $\mathbb{P}(H > 7) < 0.2$ by calculating four binomials, and you know that $\mathbb{E}(H | H < 7)$ is less than $5$. Then by assuming the tail probabilities are uniform (which will give an overestimate) and noting that the additional expectation is bounded by $H$, we have

$$ \mathbb{E}(\text{total}) < 5 \cdot 0.8 + \frac{14+16+18+20}{4} \cdot 0.2 < 8. $$
[As the function $5p + 17(1-p)$ is decreasing in $p$, taking $p = 0.8$ suffices.]

Answer (score 1):

A very quick and dirty approximation: Let $X$ be the number of heads in the initial $10$ tosses. Let $Y$ be the number of heads in the bonus tosses. Clearly $E[X]=5$.

One only gets into the bonus with $7$ or more heads. This happens with probability $\frac{1+10+45+120}{1024}=\frac{176}{1024}$. Let's overestimate that probability as $0.2$. In these cases you get at most $20$ bonus tosses. Let's be very generous and take $20$ bonus tosses every time we get $7$ or more heads (again an overestimate). Each time you take $20$ bonus tosses you get an average of $10$ (additional) heads.

So $E[Y]<0.2\cdot 10=2$.

So we have that the expected total number of heads (by linearity of expectation) satisfies:
$$E[X+Y]=E[X]+E[Y]<5+2=7$$

Safely within given answer of "between $0$ and $8$".

P.S. I think that the actual expected value is $5+\frac{665}{1024}$, but that requires a more careful calculation.

Answer (score 0):

$\def\ed{\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}}$
You can simplify the calculation by using the rules
$$
\mathbb{E}(H_2|N)=\frac{N}{2}
$$
and
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(H_2)&=\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(H_2|N))\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}(N)\ ,
\end{align}
where $\ H_2\ed X-H\ $ is the number of heads occurring in the second group of tosses, and
\begin{align}
N&\ed\max\big(0,2H-T^2\big)\\
&=\max\big(0,20-2T-T^2\big)
\end{align}
is the total number of tosses in the second group.  The random variable $\ N\ $ is positive if and only if $ 0\le T\le3\ $. Therefore
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(N)&=\frac{1}{2^{10}}\sum_{t=0}^3\big(20-2t-t^2\big){10\choose t}\\
&=\frac{665}{512}
\end{align}
and
$$
\mathbb{E}\big(H_2\big)=\frac{665}{1024}\ .
$$